# 'QuerySet' object is not callable

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this function that must get the class code, and then look for this class in the database, then fill in the `participant` field of this class with the user who is authenticated.

`def participar(request):
cc = nameUser(request)

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    busca = request.POST.get('busca')
    turma = Turma.objects.filter(codigo=busca)
    
    obj = turma(participantes=request.user)
    obj.save()

else:
    return render(request, 'turmas/participar.html', cc)    

return render(request, 'turmas/participar.html', cc)`
```

but when trying to add the following error occurs on the line `turma(participantes=request.user)`

'QuerySet' object is not callable

what was expected is that after searching for the desired class by its code, the authenticated user would be added to the participant field of that class

Comment: `turma` is a queryset of 0 to many `Turma` objects.  Add your **models.py** and I might be able to show you how to do what I think you're trying to do.

Comment: Guessing you want this: `turma.filter(participantes=request.user)`